# Deleting element with D3 fails

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Deleting dom with D3 fails
Hello everyone. I try to use D3 to manipulate doms, which are defined in html ahead of time.
Content in html:

```
<div>
 <p class="child" id="1">James</p>
 <p class="child" id="2">Kate</p>
```

D3 code:

```
var div = d3.select('div')
var pp = div.selectAll('p.child');
var ppUpdate = pp.data(dataset, d =>d.id);
var ppexit = ppUpdate.exit();
ppexit.remove();
```

I use the following data for testing:
var data1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'James' }, { id: 4, name: 'Jordan' }];

Error when running to "pp.data"：
[image]

I modified the relevant code to:

```
var ppUpdate = pp.data(dataset, d => {
   if(d){
     return d.id
   }
 });
```

There will be no errors. But "ppUpdate.exit();" doesn't return the record I want to delete, instead it returns both records in the html. Further tracing the code execution process, in the "bindKey" function in d3.js, the correct "keyValue" cannot be obtained.
[image]

Please, how can I complete my function? thanks.

Comment: It seems like you're using enter/exit pattern improperly. Can you post the full code (including `enter`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument in `selection.data()`, that you named `d`, is the datum of the element. The important information is that the key function is evaluated on the elements and on the data; however, the elements initially have no data bound to them, so the datum is `null`.

What you want is to get the element's `id` first:

```
var ppUpdate = pp.data(dataset, (d, i, n) => d ? d.id : n[i].id);
```

Notice that because you had an arrow function in your question I cannot use `this`, so I'm using `n[i]` to get the element.

Here is the working snippet:

```js
var dataset = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'James'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'Jordan'
}];
var div = d3.select('div')
var pp = div.selectAll('p.child');
var ppUpdate = pp.data(dataset, (d, i, n) => d ? d.id : n[i].id);
var ppexit = ppUpdate.exit();
ppexit.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="child" id="1">James</p>
  <p class="child" id="2">Kate</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your scenario is useful. I'm still a new d3 user. It also needs to be studied in depth. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello. I checked a lot of d3 information and found that "data" is bound to "function(d) { return d; }" or "function(d, i) ", how do you know that you can bind "function(d, n, i)" of this type?Thanks.@Gerardo Furtado

Comment: They key function passes three arguments, you can use how many you want.

Comment: Hello. I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you give an example of how you decide to pass multiple parameters? Thank you. @Gerardo Furtado

Comment: @moneybags It's better explained here: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data